# Setting up Tower 2 with Git Two Factor Authentication

Tags: github, two-factor-authentication, git-tower

I have turned on my github's two factor authentication. I am able to push and pull from the terminal but not able to do it via Tower. I am able to see all my branches in tower, but not able to push, pull or fetch.

I have tried to do it via SSH and HTTPS.

I keep getting this following error.

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
```

I have tried to login with Oauth and also access toke, but no luck yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this still a problem?

Comment: no i figured it out eventually

Comment: It would be great for other user's if you could write an answer and share what helped you, so they can sort things out if they run into this question (e.g. through google) @Ronaldoh1

Answer (score 2):

Try to open "Keychain Access" and there lock & unlock your "login" keychain, it solved the issue for me.